# Regex for extracting two numbers with a between and end pattern

Tags: r, regex

I need to extract two numbers under certain conditions: cumulativelly, the first one need to be followed by a `/A`, AND the second one must be followed by a `B`. For instance:

- `30A/305B`: both 30 and 305 must be returned;
- `30/305B`: neither 30 nor 305 would be returned;
- `30A/305`: neither 30 nor 305 would be returned;

As per [here](https://regex101.com/r/rkAKG5/1), I tried the regex below without success:

```
(\d+(?=A\/))(\d+(?=B))
```

How do I get it done?
I am using R , with option `perl = TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `(\d+(?=A\/))(\d+(?=B))` matches 1 or more digits, and asserts (not match) `A/` directly to the left.

That first assertion will be true, but after this assertion there is a second part that starts with matching 1 or more digits again.

That can not work, as the previous assertion just asserted that there is `A/`

---

You don't need any lookarounds or perl = TRUE,  you can use 2 capture groups instead:

```
(\d+)A/(\d+)B
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gq3Tya/1)

```
str <- "30A/305B: both 30 and 305 must be returned;"
str_match(str, "(\\d+)A/(\\d+)B")
```

Output

```
     [,1]       [,2] [,3] 
[1,] "30A/305B" "30" "305"
```

Comment: Sure, got it! Thank you.